# Unit Conversions with standard deviation

Tags: probability, variance, standard-deviation

When converting units of standard deviation, should I do the calculations in variance then convert the variance back?

For reference, I am trying to convert the standard deviation from fahrenheit to celsius. I have a standard deviation of 0.9 so I am doing $\frac{5}{9}*0.9^2$=0.45. Then I did $\sqrt45$ to get my new standard deviation; since the equation for converting is: $celsius=\frac{5}{9}(farenheit-32)$. But I think I am over complicating it and should just directly convert the standard deviation to celsius without converting to the variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The units of variance are the square of the units used for the distribution.  You can verify that from the defining equation for variance.  If you want to convert the variance of a number measured in $^\circ F$ to a number measured in $^\circ C$ you need to multiply by $\left(\frac 59\right)^2$.  The units of standard deviation are the same as the units of the distribution, so if you are converting a standard deviation you multiply by $\frac 59$

Comment: As a follow-up question what if I am given standard deviation and want my new units to be in the variance? Do I convert the standard deviation to variance before converting my units, or do I wait until I have converted my standard deviation into my new units to find my new variance?

Comment: Keep it simple, @user: variance is the square of the standard deviation.  So... square it.  $$(0.9^\circ\mathrm F)^2 = (0.72^2)^\circ\mathrm C^2$$

Comment: When I do $0.9^2$*$\frac{5}{9}$ I get 0.45. I assume the error is on my side.

Comment: @User did you forget the square on the 5/9?

Comment: @User:  for your first comment, you can convert in either order you want.  The conversion factor for variance is the square of the conversion factor for standard deviation.  It helps if you write the quantities with units.  If you are measuring the length of a rod, the length and standard deviation are in meters.  The variance is in $m^2$.  If you want to convert a standard deviation in m to a variance in ft$^2$, you can convert the std deviation to ft by multiplying by $3.28$, then square to get the variance, or square and then multiply by $3.28^2$ because you are converting $m^2$ to $ft^2$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, keep it simple.

If your standard deviation is $0.9^\circ\mathrm F$, then it is $(\tfrac 450.9)^\circ\mathrm C$.  ... that is: $0.72^\circ\mathrm C$.

We do not include the term of $-32$ because we are measuring in *displacement* from the mean temperature (well, the square root of the expected square of the displacement from the mean).   So we are only concerned about the scale.